# Firebase Deploy Link shows Blank or Deploy complete

Tags: firebase, deployment

`

```js
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`Have an issue where the Firebase deploy link shows "Firebase Hosting Setup Complete." I've tried just about everything on stackoverflow with no success.

I have it set to "build" not "public" in my firebase.json for hosting and it's not doing anything.
I've tried messing with the index.html but then the screen just comes up white/blank.

I've also deleted firebase files completely and started the init over. Still comes back the same.

Has anyone else ran into this lately?

Comment: Are you deploying a vanilla JS web application? Using a framework like React, Angular, NextJS etc?

Comment: Rafael, I’m using React.

Comment: did you run `firebase init` in your project? If you do, and select hosting it will generate a json config file for hosting that will be used when you run`firebase deploy`

Comment: Yeah, I’ve done that. I’ve even deleted the files and restarted the process about 9 times. ‍♂️

Comment: Can you please add your generated firebase hosting file. Have you tried using the CI/CD automation?

Comment: I will post it once I’m home!! Thank you so much for helping me through this. Truly appreciate it!

Comment: {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the json schema as a code block with an appropriate description. This helps other people understand your issue more clearly.

Comment: I added the snippet to the question

Comment: have you tried removing the rewrites property?

Comment: Yes, I've done it without the rewrites and it still doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without any code snippets or firebase config files but I believe if you specify your public location as "build" you do not need to include the `rewrites` property in the `firebase.json` file. According to [The Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config),

Set up rewrites for any of these purposes:

- Show the same content for multiple URLs. Learn how.
- Serve a function or access a Cloud Run container from a Hosting URL. Learn how: function or container.
- Create a custom domain Dynamic Link. Learn how.